# Wifi not working on live usb

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, live-usb

I just booted up ubuntu 14.04 from a usb and am running it live but the problem is that the wifi is not working. The light on my wifi switch is not turning on but it turns on in windows.

Comment: Please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422

Answer (score 1):

What are the specs of your computer? You may have a wireless card which requires proprietary drivers that wouldn't be included in a standard ubuntu install. Plug in an ethernet cable and Run 'Additional Drivers' to rectify this. However, if you are running it live you will need to do this every time you boot. The solution would be to install the os on your hard drive and permanently install the driver. If you do not want to remove your current os you can dual boot and just use a small partition to run ubuntu. 10-20gb should be more than enough if you do not plan on keeping any space hungry files on there.
If this does not solve your problem, read the troubleshooting guide here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide